# Embedding language in home page url

Tags: iis, redirect

I am using `Sitecore 10.3` and `JSS` next app, I need to add language in the home page URL.
Ex: `https://mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com/en/`, also need all URLs to end with `/`.
can I do this from IIS??

Comment: Next.js doesn't use IIS

Answer (score 0):

You can update `middleware.ts` as below to redirect to a specific language.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
if (!req.cookies.get('Site_Language')) {
  const resp = NextResponse.redirect(
    new URL(`/${'en'}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}/`, req.url)
  );
  resp.cookies.set('Site_Language', 'en');
  return resp;
}
return middleware(req, ev);
}
```

In the above code it checks if the cookie for language does not exist, it sets the cookie and does the redirection including trailing slash in the url.

Make sure the language you are redirecting to is not set as default locale inside `next.config.js`.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to end all URLs with `/`.
But just to embed language in the URL, you can use this configuration:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <configuration>
    <linkManager>
      <providers>
        <add name="localizedProvider">
          <patch:attribute name="lowercaseUrls">true</patch:attribute>
          <patch:attribute name="languageEmbedding">true</patch:attribute> 
        </add>
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
    <links>
      <urlBuilder>
        <lowercaseUrls>true</lowercaseUrls>
        <languageEmbedding>always</languageEmbedding>
      </urlBuilder>
    </links>
  </configuration>
</sitecore>
```